# How to create multiple subplots from statsmodels for Bland-Altman plot

Tags: subplot

I plotted 3 bland-altman plots as 1, now i'm trying to add the right label for each plot and then i need to save it as png.
I see that only last one has the right label (Night 3 etc) and same x and y axis limits (x = 0, 55 and y = -8,8). How can i fix it?

here is the code i used:

```py
f, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, figsize =(8,15))

sm.graphics.mean_diff_plot(Valid_3nights.AHI_1, Valid_3nights.AHI_Reference, ax=ax)
plt.xlabel("Reference AHI (events/hr)")
plt.ylabel("Night 1 - Reference\nAHI (events/hr)")

plt.xlim(0, 55)
plt.ylim(-8, 8)


sm.graphics.mean_diff_plot(Valid_3nights.AHI_2, Valid_3nights.AHI_Reference, ax=ax2)
plt.xlabel("Reference AHI (events/hr)")
plt.ylabel("Night 2 - Reference\nAHI (events/hr)")

plt.xlim(0, 55)
plt.ylim(-8, 8)


sm.graphics.mean_diff_plot(Valid_3nights.AHI_3, Valid_3nights.AHI_Reference, ax=ax3)
plt.xlabel("Reference AHI (events/hr)")
plt.ylabel("Night 3 - Reference\nAHI (events/hr)")

plt.xlim(0, 55)
plt.ylim(-8, 8)


plt.show()
```

Comment: I think instead of using pyplot `plt.xlabel`, `plt.xlim` you need to use the corresponding method for the axes axi.